# making sql query to get first id of a tourist and then all of it's surcharges

Tags: .net, sql

I've got these tables in my database:

**Tourist** - this is the first table

```
Tourist_ID - primary key
Excursion_ID - foreign key
Name...etc...
```

**EXTRA_CHARGES**

```
Extra_Charge_ID - primmary key 

Excursion_ID - foreign key

  Extra_Charge_Description
```

**Tourist_Extra_Charges**

```
Tourist_Extra_charge_ID

Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key

Tourist_ID - foreign key
```

**Reservations**
Reservation_ID - primary key

.....
**Tourist_Reservations**

```
Tourist_Reservation_ID

Reservation_ID - foreign key

Tourist_ID - foreign key
```

So here is my example: I've got reservation with Reservaton_ID - 27 This reservation has two tourists with Tourist_ID - 86 and Tourist_ID - 87 This Tourist with id 86 has extra charges with Extra_Charge_ID - 7 and and Extra_charge_ID - 11; The Tourist with ID 87 has  extra charge with ID - 10;

Is it possible to make sql query and the name and id of the tourist and then all of its extra charges

Sothe output to look like:

Tourist_ID: 86, Name:JOHN, EXTRA CHARGES: 7,11

(Here is the query I made to get the extra_charge_description of all of the tourists with Reservation_ID = 27 )

```
Select EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID FROM EXTRA_CHARGES

         INNER JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES on EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID

 INNER JOIN TOURIST_RESERVATION on TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = TOURIST_RESERVATION.Tourist_ID
          INNER JOIN  RESERVATIONS on RESERVATIONS.Reservation_ID = TOURIST_RESERVATION.Reservation_IDhe e
          where RESERVATIONS.Reservation_ID=27
```

The problem here is that I have three records

SO if you tink that there is a way in .net to get first the name and then all the extra charges of this name - please advice because I'm new to .net

Comment: For SQL Server or MySQL or...?

Comment: I've Written SQL Server.k I know that in MYSQL it will work with Group_Concat

Comment: Use LINQ for getting records in .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your schema correctly, this should do what you're looking for;

```
SELECT t.Tourist_ID, t.Name, 
  STUFF((
    SELECT CAST(',' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(tec.Extra_Charge_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM Tourist_Extra_Charges tec
    WHERE tec.Tourist_ID = t.Tourist_ID
    ORDER BY tec.Extra_Charge_ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS Charges
FROM Tourist t;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5126b/1).

Comment: You saveeeeeed my life :))) THAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANk YOUUUUU!